# A text label in the tableview is too long which affects the right detail (detailTextLabel) to be covered or not shown

Tags: uitableview, detailtextlabel

I have set a text for that cell but however, the text that it is shown is too long which affects the right detail text to be covered or not shown.

I can't change it as I need the name in the next viewcontroller. Is it possible to enable it to just display the text, followed by "...."?

EXAMPLE:

Electrical & Electronic Engi.... 01 >

LEGEND:
"Electrical & Electronic Engi...." as text displayed in the tableview, "01" as the detailTextLabel on the right and the ">" as the navigation.

This is how it should look like, http://oi58.tinypic.com/2j4vg5k.jpg, but due to some text is too long, this is what appears: http://oi58.tinypic.com/erc177.jpg

The textLabel and detailTextLabel doesn't seem to fit or show in the whole row. I would like the right detailTextLabel to be still there will the textLabel to end with a "...."

Thanks.

(I'm new to iOS Programming)

Comment: I would like to only set that particular row to display as that and the rest just as per normal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you like to display? Can you type in text of desired format in which you want to display?

Comment: @ViruMax I have added and changed the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you will have to restrict the width of default textLabel of UITableViewCell or add new UILabel to cell.

you have two options

1)Dont use default textLabel of cell, create new UILabel and add it as a subview of tableview cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell using custom cell

    //restrict width here while creating label (change 40 to what you want)
    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,20)];

   tempLabel.text=@"The text you want to assign";
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



        [[cell contentView] addSubview:tempLabel];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

2)Or second way is to change width of default textLabel , for this you will have to create new subclass inheriting UITableViewCell, and in the subclass override method (void)layoutSubView and in that method change width(do it by trial and error method)

create new class with following .h and .m file

```
////CustomCell .h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end

////CustomCell .m file

#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect tempFrame=self.textLabel.frame;

     //whatever you want to set
     tempFrame.width=30;
     self.textLabel.frame=tempFrame;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Or one different option(better one)

3) Create custom tableview cell

[custom tableview cell tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

And for having ... at the end of UILabel, there is property truncateTail of UILabel. you can  use that.

Comment: For the first example, may I know how do I set and get a detailTextLabel?

Comment: try to use default detailTextLabel, let me know is it working or not.

Comment: try to check height of main text label, it might possible that it is hiding it, try by giving different background colours to both labels, whether they are visible, else like text label add new detail text label.

Answer (score 1):

Although the cell configuration is a bit different (only detail label and no disclosure indicator) this answer might be helpful: [How can I truncate text in a UITableView Cell TextLabel so it doesn't hide the DetailTextLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308465/how-can-i-truncate-text-in-a-uitableview-cell-textlabel-so-it-doesnt-hide-the-d/29495427#29495427)