# UITable detailViewLabel formatting affecting textLablel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UITableView` and I'm having trouble with the formatting of the cells.

This is what it looks like this: "[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFIQB.png)"

As you can see, the cells *with* a percent grade have the `textLabel` (the class name) higher than the cells without the percent grade.
The problem is in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the `UITableViewDelegate`. I set the text of the `textLabel` (the part of the table view with the class name) and then `if` the `detailTextLabel` has a percent, I set the `cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;`. I don't see why this affects the `textLabel` though. I thought the two labels in the content view were independent of each other.

How would I fix this problem and get my labels to format correctly?

Comment: Why not set the detail label to always have 2 lines? You don't need to have any text in the second line.

Comment: I could do that but then the class name will be slightly higher, because the `[label sizeToFit]` will make it so that there are two lines where the class name is on the top line... Is there some way I can keep the class name (ie the `textLabel`) as a one line label while making the `detailTextLabel` always two?

Comment: i don't think it be higher if there's no text, [sizeToFit] consider the text in the label and then calculate the size, i think :)

Comment: Use Custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: @DekelMaman I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @Ricky if I do a custom UITableViewCell, what specific settings would you recommend changing to allow that?

Comment: If you do a custom UITableViewCell, you can have 3 UILabels for 1 tableCell (With %) and another UITableViewCell with only 2 UILabels (Without %). You will need to know which type of cell to use during the cell creation in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @Ricky yeah that's will be the right way to do that... :)

Comment: I think @ViruMax has an easier solution, use the `detailTextLabel` but just use a `UILabel` for the class name... So it's just the class name I have to re add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by adding two separate new labels in your cell. Don't use the default labels.
You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084094/a-text-label-in-the-tableview-is-too-long-which-affects-the-right-detail-detail/22138866#22138866) for code snippet and for more detailed explanation.