# How can I truncate text in a UITableView Cell TextLabel so it doesn't hide the DetailTextLabel?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a list of phone rates, the `textLabel` is the country/territory and the `detailTextLabel` is the rate I have to display.

For some strings, the `textLabel` is too long and the `detailTextLabel` becomes hidden. Is there a setting to automatically adjust the text with `…` if it's too long?

Here is an example where `Central African Republic (Mobile)` has this issue:

[image: example]

Comment: Are you using a storyboard with prototype cells?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's not my code. But I set the data in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Right, so it's a standard UICell, nothing custom about it right?

Comment: Yes, standard. I found this cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, but it doesn't seem to work with UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Answer (score 5):

On laying out a cell with UITableViewCellStyle.Value1 style the title label seems to get priority and push the detail label out of view. The solution might be to subclass UITableViewCell and override its layoutSubviews():

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let detail = self.detailTextLabel {
            // this will do the actual layout of the detail 
            // label's text, so you can get its width
            detail.sizeToFit() 

            // you might want to find a clever way to calculate this
            // instead of assigning a literal
            let rightMargin: CGFloat = 16

            // adjust the detail's frame
            let detailWidth = rightMargin + detail.frame.size.width
            detail.frame.origin.x = self.frame.size.width - detailWidth
            detail.frame.size.width = detailWidth
            detail.textAlignment = .Left

            // now truncate the title label        
            if let text = self.textLabel {
                if text.frame.origin.x + text.frame.size.width > self.frame.width - detailWidth {
                    text.frame.size.width = self.frame.width - detailWidth - text.frame.origin.x
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that although `detail.textAlignment = .Left` we account for detail's width and the actual text ends up aligned to the right.

Comment: You can account for an accessory type by updating `let detailWidth = rightMargin + detail.frame.size.width` to -> `let detailWidth = rightMargin + detail.frame.size.width + (self.accessoryType != .none ? 20 : 0)`

Answer (score 0):

So what you probably need to do is manually fix the width of the textLabel, since by default it takes up the whole width of the cell. To do this, you can do the following:

```
CGRect textLabelFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
textLabelFrame.size.width -= DETAIL_LABEL_WIDTH;
cell.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
```

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, where DETAIL_LABEL_WIDTH is the width you want for the detailTextLabel. Assuming the label is auto-ellipsizing, which it should be, this will cause the text to add a "..." at the end of the label right before the detail text label if the width is longer than the width you are setting above.